# xpath: Is it possible to select ancestor nodes that have a certain descendant?

Tags: xpath

First I need an element `a` with a certain descendant `d`

```
//a/b/c/d[@class='gotcha']
```

Then I want to perform some further search from `a`, say take another descendant:

```
//a/b/c/d[@class='gotcha']/../../../b2/c2/d2
```

Is there any shortcut for going N levels up? Ideally I want to somehow select "a, which have certain descendants" for further usage.

UPD: sample xml

```
<a>
 <b>
  <c><d class='gotcha'></d></c>
 </b>
 <b2>
  <c2><d2></d2></c2>
 </b2>
</a>
```

I need d2, knowing the structure and 'gotcha' value which can change.

Comment: Show sample XML or HTML, and mark exactly what you want to select.  Then we'll be able to come up with a concise XPath.   Guessing from your (suspect) XPaths is very non-ideal.  Thanks.

Comment: html: http://www.foxsports.com.au/afl what I want to extract: links from "women's afl" news section. The working xpath I'm currently using: //section[@class='breaking-news']/header/h1[re:test(text(), 'women')]/../../div/ol/li/article/header/div/h1[@itemprop='name headline']/a/@href.   Not sure if you want this rather than simplified example.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in the content of the question itself so that it'll continue to be valuable to future readers if the link changes in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking for is

```
//a[b/c/d[@class='gotcha']]/b2/c2/d2
```

That is:

- Find an element `a` anywhere

  - that has a `b` child that has a `c` child that has a `d` child with attribute `class='gotcha'`
- Now from the `a` element(s) selected so far, find the `b2` child's `c2` child's `d2` child element.

Notes:

- The word "child" in XPath means an immediate child, not a grandchild or any other descendant. The original question above uses "child" to mean "descendant", which is misleading and confusing.
- An XPath expression will select *all* applicable nodes. So all the singular nouns in the above explanation can be plural.
- You could also use `//a[b/c/d/@class='gotcha']/b2/c2/d2`, which would be equivalent to the above, but I think using the inner predicate better explains the thought process.